# The scope of online flight navigation apps and websites on Aviation SE

Tags: discussion

There is an emerging "hobby" of flight tracking. Websites and apps offer close to real-time positioning, along with information on each aircraft and journey. [FlightStats](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightTracker/flightTracker.do), [FlightRadar24](http://www.flightradar24.com/37.84,23.92/10), and [FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/live/), are some of the sites.

I use Apple devices but the apps are generally cross platform. These include app versions of the sites listed, but also PlaneFinder, FlightBoard (airport information), FlightUpdate, and FlightStatus.

So, my question is whether these would be permitted? I always wonder if these services are: used by professionals, dangerous, accurate, and useful (as a teaching tool).

Finally, this area has started relatively recently, and I'm sure, will have more and more services as the technology permits.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  Would what be permitted here?

Comment: Discussions and questions about these technologies..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think much of what can be said / needs to be said about these apps has already been said (see [online-radar](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-radar) & [flightradar24](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flightradar24)) - we've talked about the technology underlying them (ADS-B & RADAR), and some of the "interesting behavior" you might observe when using these sorts of plane-tracking websites/apps.

In terms of what is/isn't "on topic" here, I think questions about something interesting you're seeing a flight do on these apps could be on-topic ([like this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/why-did-this-aircraft-re-route), or [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5182/why-is-the-flight-going-north-just-to-go-south)) when there's a reasonable explanation we can give.
These would need to be considered on a case-by-case basis -- sometimes there's just no way to even reasonably speculate, and "we don't know" is a pretty awful answer to give someone - those questions would be "Too Broad" for us to answer here.

---

Questions *about a specific application or website* (especially "How do I do X with website Y?" type questions) are almost certainly off-topic - We aren't (and can't be) technical support for all the flight-tracking software out there.
That kind of question would be better suited for the app/website's support team, or possibly [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) than the main site (I'm sure a lot of folks in chat know the ins-and-outs of these apps well enough to field basic questions).

Comment: Your answer is right on.. It occurs to me that in the summary of the Aviation SE, you guys might want to be explicit about what's ok and what's not.. And thanks for the links ..

Comment: @DavidDelMonte While not perfect, we are working on that:  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/282/69).